# Union of a family of elements of $V_\kappa$ indexed by an element of $V_\kappa$ is in $V_\kappa$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Let $\kappa$ be an inaccessible cardinal, and let $I \to V_\kappa$ be a function,
where $I \in V_\kappa$ and $\forall i \in I, f(i) \in V_\kappa$.

> Why would $\bigcup_{i \in I} f(i)$ be in $V_\kappa$?

The following result could be useful, I guess, but I can neither find nor come up with it's proof myself:

> If $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal, then $\forall x, x \in V_\kappa \Leftrightarrow x \subseteq V_\kappa, |x| < \kappa$.

If we know the latter result, of course, the the first one is a trivial corollary: as $I, f(i)$'s $ \in V_\kappa$, then $|I|,|f(i)|$'s $< \kappa$, and $\kappa$ regular implies $|\bigcup_{i \in I} f(i)| < \kappa;$ and $\bigcup_{i \in I} f(i) \subseteq V_\kappa$.

I conjecture somehow the knowledge of $\kappa$ being strong limit. As of now, there must be some other connection of $V_\alpha$ with the concept of cardinality I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\subset \kappa$, we can define $rk : x\to \kappa$ by $rk(y) := \min\{\alpha\in \kappa \mid y\in V_\alpha\}$.

If moreover $|x|<\kappa$, then $rk$ cannot be cofinal since $\kappa$ is regular. Therefore it is bounded above, say by $\delta<\kappa$. Therefore $x\subset V_\delta$, $x\in V_{\delta+1}\subset V_\kappa$, so $x\in V_\kappa$

Conversely if $x\in V_\kappa$, then clearly $x\subset V_\kappa$. Moreover one can prove by induction that $|V_\alpha| <\kappa$ for $\alpha < \kappa$ : this is clearly true for $\alpha= 0$, it goes through at successor stages since $\kappa$ is strong limit, and at limit stages since $\kappa$ is regular.

Comment: One can even prove that the equivalence $x\in V_\kappa\iff x\subseteq V_\kappa\land|x|<\kappa$ is itself equivalent to $\kappa$ being [strongly] inaccessible.

Comment: @Max I'm not sure how regularity of $\kappa$ implies that there is $\delta < \kappa$ so that $rk|x| $. Could you give more details, please?

Comment: The range of the function $rk$ is of cardinality at most $|x| <\kappa$. Since $\kappa$ is regular, this range is not cofinal, therefore it is bounded, by definition of cofinality : there is $\delta<\kappa$, such that the range of $rk$ is below $\delta$